# Moving SQL Server from one datacenter to another datacenter

Tags: sql-server

I am working on to find some workaround for moving SQL Server 2005/2008 instances from one data center to another data center without changing database configuration setting at application end because application team is not sure what all places server name and database name is hardcoded. I know this is bad practice but application is developed by third party and we don't have control on application code.

So challenge here is to keep the server name and database name and IP is same.

Note : OS is not supporting for Image Backup so this option is ruled out.

Please let me know your thought.

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: Server names and ip addresses are not programming related questions.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.